# Messages out of order in message window of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arctoolbox

When I run custom tool I'd like to see tool's messages. This is why I set this geoprocessing option:

[image]

During tool execution I see this:

[image]

Which is wrong because I have these 2 lines in my code:

```
arcpy.AddMessage("Processing links")
.....
arcpy.AddMessage ("All links assigned to nodes \n")
```

When I go to History to view details I see this:

[image]

Which is expected order and count of messages.

Images here to show what's actually happening, because in clipboard everything looks fine.

Is there any setting that I am missing?

Comment: ArcGIS Pro is an asyncronous multithreaded application.

Comment: I sometimes see messaging like you report.  Explaining it is not my expertise but @MichaelStimson's comment sounds like it could be on the money.

Comment: @PolyGeo it is possible, but something messed up anyway. It is all started with Client complaining of not seeing messages at all! Sorting slaves/threads messages after completion is not a big deal...

Comment: This looks like a bug in the GP Framework: Something might be finishing before pulling all the messages from the internal message queue. I'd report to tech support if you can.